# Swift 3- Displaying a list of previously shown local notifications within the UI

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am wondering if there is a way to show notifications within the user interface of my swift app. I have background notifications working however I want to see a list of previously alerted notifications in a tableview/viewController, sort of like a mini notification center.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When ever you receive a notification add to an array. Then you can use that array to show it in a table view. If you need persistence you could even store it in core data

Comment: Great thanks for that!